# What does "$\mathbb{R}$-complete" mean in Woodin's paper?

Tags: field-theory, ordered-fields

I'm reading Woodin's paper "A Discontinuous Homomorphism from C(X) without CH".
In this paper, Woodin defined "$\mathbb{R}$-complete" as the following:

*DEFINITION 1. Suppose that $\mathbb{H} \subset  \mathbb{F}$ are real-closed fields and $\mathbb{R} \subset \mathbb{F}$. The subfield
$\mathbb{H}$ is $\mathbb{R}$-complete if whenever $(A,B)$ is an $(\omega,\omega)$ gap in $\mathbb{G}$, either $(A,B)$ is a gap in $\mathbb{H}$
or $r \in \mathbb{H}$ where $r$ is the real defined by $(A,B)$, that is, $r = \sup A $ in $\mathbb{R}$.*

What does "$\mathbb{G}$" mean?
He asserts that "$\mathbb{H}$ is $\mathbb{R}$ -complete" is equivalent to "$\mathbb{H} \cap \mathbb{R}$ is equal to the residue field of $\mathbb{H}$". 
 However, this does not refer to $\mathbb{G}$.

Comment: Might be a typo for $\mathbb F$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that $\mathbb{G}$ is a typo and should be $\mathbb{Q}$ instead.  An $(\omega,\omega)$-gap in $\mathbb{Q}$ is then just a gap in $\mathbb{Q}$ where an irrational number is, so $\mathbb{H}$ being $\mathbb{R}$-complete just means that if it contains any element in such a gap, it contains the real number in it.  That is, whenever $\mathbb{H}$ contains an element that is infinitesimally close to an irrational number, it contains that irrational number.  (Or equivalently, whenever $\mathbb{H}$ contains an element that is infinitesimally close to a real number, it contains that real number.)

Comment: Thank you! It seem to be gone well.